# Rails sorting or ordering query is slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord, pagination

Using Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9, will_paginate. I have 100,000 records, and tested the following queries:

```
# 1000+ms to load
@shops = Shop.where(:shop_type => @type).paginate(:include => :photos, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 25, :order => 'created_at DESC')

# 1000+ms to load
@shops = Shop.paginate(:include => :photos, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 25, :order => 'created_at DESC')

# 1000+ms to load
@shops = Shop.order('created_at DESC').limit(25)

# 1+ms to load
@shops = Shop.paginate(:include => :photos, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
```

I noticed that the `order` option is incredibly slow. Test results show that `will_paginate` is not a problem.

How should I change it so that the query with `order` can be sped up.

Comment: add an index on the order column?

Comment: @apneadiving Thought of that. Anything that could be sorted/ordered must be indexed?

Comment: Only if you want it fast.  Indexes are pretty cheap comparatively speaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, try to create index on the order column. It will speed it up.